# Best direction for displaying game graphics in C# App

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+

I am making a small game as sort of a test project, nothing major. I just started and am working on the graphics piece, but I'm not sure the best way to draw the graphics to the screen.

It is going to be sort of like the old Zelda, so pretty simple using bitmaps and such. I started thinking that I could just paint to a Picture Box control using Drawing.Graphics with the Handle from the control, but this seems cumbersome. I'm also not sure if I can use double buffering with this method either.

I looked at XNA, but for now I wanted to use a simple method to display everything.

So, my question. Using the current C# windows controls and framework, what is the best approach to displaying game graphics (i.e. Picture Box, build a custom control, etc.)

EDIT:
I will add how I am currently drawing to the picture box. I have a Tile object that just contains the pixels for the tile ( `List< List< Color>> texture;` ), nothing more for simplicity. I then draw that to the pic box by iterating through the pixels and using the FillRectangle method using a brush with the current pixel color and the size specified by a scale variable:

```
int scale = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < texture.Width;)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < texture.Height; ++j)
    {
        int x = i * scale;
        int y = j * scale;
        picBox.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(currentPixelColor), new Rectangle(x, y, scale, scale));
    }
}
```

Yah, pretty cumbersome. Any suggestions or comments are appreciated.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284694/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-simulate-radar-in-c/1321945#1321945) for a sample application (source code included) that will get you started.

Comment: I really think you should reconsider using XNA. A simple override of `Draw()` suffice to draw an object on screen. Plus it has a handful of utility methods, extensibility and so on for creating games.

Comment: Can you expand on why you think it is cumbersome? If you think GDI is cimbersome, I dont think XNA/DirectX/OpenGL/etc will be of any help in the simplicity category.

Comment: XNA is certainly simpler and easier than drawing everything yourself, but as a result it's less of a learning experience, not to mention that it locks you in to the XNA way of doing things.

Comment: I believe XNA is one of the simplest API, as simple as GDI+ but faster. Managed Direct-X & .net 3'd party engines (such as TrueVision) are more complex. WPF is direct-x based also but more user-interface-centric :)

Comment: MusiGenesis, I totally agree, and being locked into that framework is the main reason I wanted to look at other venues. Plus, I don't think XNA is cross platform is it?

Comment: Mike Webb, the sample you posted is totally unnecessary.  GDI will size rects for you given source and destination rects.  Not to mention you have two "new" calls in your loop that should be hoisted out to improve performance.

Comment: Neil N, thanks for the comments. The code above is exactly why I am posting here. I used the scale variable because a 16x16 pixel image is tiny, obviously and I wanted to scale it to the size I wanted. Will GDI+ scale small images to the size that I want them easily? Also, would it be better to store the tile textures as bitmaps instead of using only their pixels (i.e. am I trying to simplify too much)?

Comment: Everyone, thanks for your suggestions. Give me a few days to dink around with XNA again and look through/try out your suggestions, and I will accept one of your answers.

Comment: @Mike: GDI+ *can* scale small images so they're drawn larger, but this isn't usually advisable in a game application. For this to look decent, you have to call `DrawImage` on a `Graphics` object with its `InterpolationMode` set to `HighQualityBicubic` (or one of the other high-quality modes), which slows down the operation considerably. Your most performant approach would be to start with an image of whatever size you want and draw that without any scaling. Or draw the smaller image scaled once to a larger image, and then draw the larger image unscaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend, that you take another look at XNA and try a few samples. It is really simple to make simple games with XNA as long as you stick with 2D. The framework does an excellent job at wrapping all the details in a easy to understand flow, where you basically fill in the blanks so to speak.

I did a complete (but very simple) Xbox game for my son in just 8 hours without little previous experience.

If you move to 3D things become more complex, as you have to understand various view models, shaders and so forth, but for 2D it is really simple to get started.

Another advantage of 2D is that the required tools are easier to get. I did all the graphics using Photoshop, the sounds were MP3s and voices I recorded using the Windows recorder. For 3D you need complex tools for building and exporting models and so forth.

Comment: I did think about the fact that I could pop the game on the XBox, which would be awesome, but I wanted to go cross platform if I wanted, too. Can XNA be cross platform, or would I have to recode my project for another platform?

Comment: Not unless you count Windows, Xbox, Zune and the upcoming Windows Phone as cross platform. However, because of the somewhat restricted setup the developer experience is really good. You use Visual Studio and to develop and debug games running on the console. It is really smooth imo. Only drawback is the $100 license to be able to deploy to the Xbox. If you just want to do Windows games there's no license.

Comment: Is there a pretty good comprehensive tutorial or help site for learning XNA?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but is it possible to deploy a C# WinForms app to the Xbox?

Comment: There are lots of useful tutorials on the XNA Creators Club site http://creators.xna.com/en-US/. I also picked up a couple of books but none of them were really good imo.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: WinForms is not supported on the Xbox. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198211(XNAGameStudio.10).aspx

Comment: @Brian: thanks for the link. I got all excited when I saw that xbox supports a subset of the compact framework, but then I saw that it doesn't even support `System.Drawing`. Oh well.

Comment: Wound up looking into XNA again. Pretty simple stuff. Looks like I'll be using it. Thanks for the suggestions and comments all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly believe XNA is by far one of the simplest game design frameworks I've used. Aside from that you could utilize WPF to draw objects on screen.

Answer (score 0):

First I strongly recommend using **XNA** or **DirectX** for game development...

However, if you do not want **XNA** nor **DirectX** help.... then you will be forced to use **[.Net GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(VS.85).aspx)** painting tools.....

By this way, you can draw points, lines, circles, rectangles, arcs, bitmaps, texts and many more by GDI+ (that all is -of course- available in C# and .Net...)

You may make a new simple control (or use an existing one such as image box or the form itself !), then you will have to override its `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` function... Then you will use `e.Graphics` to draw whatever you want...

**Example:**
[Simple Tetris Game Tutorial in C#](http://devcity.net/Articles/44/1/gdiplus_tetris.aspx)

**EDIT:**
Using a GDI+ to draw pixel by pixel picture is quite a performance drop!!

**Better is to draw shapes yourself (circles,.. etc)**